# What's the equation for a streamlined body?

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm interested in doing some simulations with aerodynamics, but I don't know what kind of curve a streamlined body actually is. Is there any kind of Cartesian formula for it?

Comment: If there was some unique formula for 'a streamlined body' then all streamlined things would be the same shape, and we would not need wind-tunnels and computational models to work out what shape things actually need to be.  We do need those things, so there is no answer to this question as it's currently posed.

Comment: -1 and voting to close. As it stands, the question is extremely vague (what kind of streamlined body?). The simplest formulas use only an empirical factor to calculate drag. Why is such a factor is not sufficient in your case? You could include at least a picture of a streamlined object you are interested in, along with a suggestion of a parametrization/formula for it. Regardless of this, this is in essence purely a math question ('how do I parametrize a surface in Cartesian coordinates'). Also, you should be nicer.

Comment: @tfb Wrong, you need to conduct testing to determine the equation in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NACA airfoils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_airfoil) are a good place to start.

Also, you should be nicer.